# How to get UITableView constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UITableView` with constraints. When, I try to retrieve the constraints for a `UITableView`, it's returning 0 elements. Any help?

```
self.tableView.constraints
```

Comment: where are you calling this? in `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: How/Where you want to use it ?

Comment: When an user performing to delete a row.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get table view superview constraints and check the table view as first or second item.

```
for constraint in (self.tableView.superview?.constraints)!  {
    if constraint.firstItem as! NSObject == self.tableView ||
    constraint.secondItem as! NSObject == self.tableView  {
        // table view constraints
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving constraints programatically is not a very good idea.

You can get all the constraints affecting a view using [constraintsAffectingLayout(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622432-constraintsaffectinglayout), however, you will probably get much more constraints than you expect.

The best solution is to save references to given constraints when you are adding them. If you are using a storyboard or a xib, create an `IBOutlet` for them.

Answer (score 0):

Depends where the constraints are applied.
If you have a `UITableView` in `UIViewController` and add constraints, the constraints are applied in `UIViewController` not in `UITableView`

Use this code instead:

```
self.tableView.superview?.constraints
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew that. But, `UITableViewCell` constraints would be in `UITableView` right.